# MPAndroidChart how to always show the last point in viewport?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Here https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport i found that we can use ***moveViewToX(float xIndex)*** (Moves the left side (edge) of the current viewport to the specified x-index). 
But if i need to show the last point always and does not matter how much the points there are?

Now i use ***moveViewToX(500);*** with the huge number as argument even if i have just 50 points, and its work. 
BUT, it is not right i think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use

```
int numberOfYourEntries = ...; // get the number
chart.moveViewTo(numberOfYourEntries);
```

Comment: Thanks, Philipp! Yes, i can use the code that you offered. Just wanted to know if there is a special method for my situation, which i didnt find. Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
lineChart.moveViewToX(lineChart.getXChartMax());
```

Comment: yes, it worked for me, thank you. The method Philipp gave has been invalid now